# Error with setting boxed byte to byte literal - Java

Tags: java, arraylist, byte

I have an *ArrayList* defined as:

```
private static ArrayList<Byte> allocatedBytes;
```

Apparently I can read from each element just fine with:

```
byte toWrite = allocatedBytes.get(currentByteAddress);
```

However, once I manipulate *toWrite* with bitwise operations and try to write it back into the list, the compiler consistently errors.

I have tried:

```
allocatedBytes.get(currentByteAddress) = toWrite;

allocatedBytes.get(currentByteAddress) = (Byte)toWrite;

allocatedBytes.get(currentByteAddress) = Byte(toWrite);

allocatedBytes.get(currentByteAddress) = new Byte(toWrite);

allocatedBytes.get(currentByteAddress) = Byte((byte)toWrite);
```

The error is always "Variable expected". I don't understand this.

My main goal here is to manipulate this byte on the bit level. If there is an easier way, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with bytes, boxing, or bitwise operations, it just has to do with that you can't set the elements of an `ArrayList` like that.  You need

```
 allocatedBytes.set(currentByteAddress, toWrite);
```

Comment: Funny how there error is always something else. I guess I'm too used to using ArrayLists for objects so I could get away with using _get()_ for everything. Thank you.

Comment: ...no, you can't get away with this for objects, either.  This is universal.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the `.get()` operation to assign value to the array. `.get()` will return a value, so that's why you have the `Variable expected` error.

You could use `set(index, value)` method to set the value, e.g:

```
allocatedBytes.set(currentByteAddress, toWrite);
```

Comment: Thanks, I've never had to make an ArrayList with literals, so that explains it.

Comment: The same principle applies to `ArrayList` of `Object`, e.g. you can invoke method on the returned object like: `array.get(index).doSomething();`, but you can't do `array.get(index) = new Object();`. In order to modify the array, you must use the `set()` method. Also, it'd be nice to up-vote answers that you find useful.